# Не записывает в многомерный массив

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных, json

Изначально файл data.json пустой

$text[1] это перемменная типа string в которой храниться сумма, $userId это перемменная типа integer

После запуска данного кода в data.json записывается null

```
                        $file = file_get_contents('data.json');
                        $taskList = json_decode($file, TRUE); 
                        unset($file);
                        $taskList[$userId] = array("account_id" => $text[1], "time" => time());
                        file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($taskList));
                        unset($taskList);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Изначально файл data.json пустой

В этой фразе и кроется ответ. "Пусто" - это не подпадает под понятие "JSON-строка". Или проверяйте полученные данные из файла на "пустоту":

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.json');
if(empty($file)) {
    $taskList = [];// для PHP < 5.4 - $taskList = array();
}
```

Или используйте метод `json_last_error()`

```
$taskList = json_decode($file, TRUE); 
if(json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    $taskList = [];
}
```

В крайнем случае, можно принудительно приводить тип данных к массиву (*но лично я так бы не делал*)

```
$taskList = (array)json_decode($file, TRUE);
```

P.S. Зачем на каждом шагу удалять переменные? Если нет специфической задачи, то это абсолютно лишнее телодвижение.